# Dismiss the UIImagePickerView on button click

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using image picker to take the pictures and save it into database. Once I save it in database, i put an alert view saying image is saved and when i click ok, i need to dismiss the image picker view and i need to present the another view .

Here is what i have

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

[self takePic];


}

-(void)takePic{

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate =self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

if (alertView.tag==1) {

    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker;
         [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; // here i am not able to dismiss the image picker view
        Tab *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tabbar"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}


}
```

I can dismiss the picker view, if i hadnt place the [self takepic] in the view did appear.

I also tried

```
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }];
```

but i couldnt dismiss the picker view. I am getting the warning: "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Can anyone tell me,how to dismiss the picker view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a property to switch the camera on and off

```
@property (assign) BOOL *makeCameraOff;


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


if (makeCameraOff==NO) {

    [self performSelector:@selector(takePic) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}
}

-(void)takePic{

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate =self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  //here change the BOOL value to YES,so that you can dismiss the camera view
makeCameraOff=YES;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


 }


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {


// your code to present the view controller you need;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this. I guess it will help you
In you code, you are taking a new referene of UIImagePicker by  `UIImagePickerController *picker;`
you should dismiss the same image picker

```
-(void)takePicture{

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate =self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (alertView.tag==1) {

        if (buttonIndex==0) {
            [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; // here i am not able to dismiss the image picker view

        }
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Hello" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.tag = 1;
    [alert show];
}
```